# How can I exclude a record from the query output (basing on some specific condition) using MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into SQL and I have the following problem: I have to exclude a speific record from a query output if a particular condition is verified.

I have this query that can return 0, 1, >1 records:

```
SELECT
    LS.id                                                                                                       AS livestock_id,
    LS.parent_livestock_species_id                                                                              AS parent_livestock_species_id,
    LS.livestock_species_name_en                                                                                AS livestock_species_name_en,
    IFNULL(LSN.livestock_species_name, LS.livestock_species_name_en)                                            AS livestock_species_name,        
    LSN.description                                                                                             AS description,
    LS.image_link                                                                                               AS image_link,
    (
        select count(*) from LivestockSpecies ls2 where ls2.id = 1 or ls2.parent_livestock_species_id = 1
    ) as total_number
FROM LivestockSpecies                                                                                          AS LS
LEFT JOIN LivestockSpeciesName                                                                                 AS LSN
      ON LSN.livestock_species_id = LS.id AND LSN.language_id = 1
WHERE
    LS.id = 1
OR
    LS.parent_livestock_species_id = 1
```

The **total_number** field count the total returned records and appear in each row.

I want that if this **total_number** field contains a value >1 and if the **parent_livestock_species_id** field value is **null* tis record is excluded from the query output.

Can I do something like this using SQL?

Comment: The table aliases used in the query are never defined.

Comment: @jarlh what do you mean?

Comment: FROM LivestockSpecies LS...

Comment: @jarlh they are, you just have to scroll right cause of horrible formatting :D

Comment: @B3S, I'm impressed you found them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can add a `having` clause:

```
having total_number = 1 or parent_livestock_species_id is not null
```

This answers your specific question.  There may be more appropriate ways to accomplish what you really want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT
          LS.id                                                            AS livestock_id
        , LS.parent_livestock_species_id                                   AS parent_livestock_species_id
        , LS.livestock_species_name_en                                     AS livestock_species_name_en
        , IsNULL(LSN.livestock_species_name, LS.livestock_species_name_en) AS livestock_species_name
        , LSN.description                                                  AS description
        , LS.image_link                                                    AS image_link
        , (
                 select
                        count(*)
                 from
                        LivestockSpecies ls2
                 where
                        ls2.id                             = 1
                        or ls2.parent_livestock_species_id = 1
          )
          as total_number
FROM
          LivestockSpecies AS LS
          LEFT JOIN
                    LivestockSpeciesName AS LSN
                    ON
                              LSN.livestock_species_id = LS.id
                              AND LSN.language_id      = 1
WHERE
          LS.id                             = 1
          OR LS.parent_livestock_species_id = 1

GROUP BY
          LS.id
        , LS.parent_livestock_species_id
        , LS.livestock_species_name_en
        , IsNULL(LSN.livestock_species_name, LS.livestock_species_name_en)
        , LSN.description
        , LS.image_link

HAVING
          (
                 select
                        count(*)
                 from
                        LivestockSpecies ls2
                 where
                        ls2.id                             = 1
                        or ls2.parent_livestock_species_id = 1
          )
          > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    LS.id AS livestock_id,
    LS.parent_livestock_species_id AS parent_livestock_species_id,
    LS.livestock_species_name_en AS livestock_species_name_en,
    IFNULL(LSN.livestock_species_name, LS.livestock_species_name_en) AS livestock_species_name,        
    LSN.description AS description,
    LS.image_link AS image_link,
    ls2.total_number as total_number
FROM LivestockSpecies AS LS
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT count(*) AS total_number 
   FROM LivestockSpecies ls2 
   WHERE ls2.id = 1 OR ls2.parent_livestock_species_id = 1
    ) ls2
  ON 1=1 AND ls2.total_number>0
LEFT JOIN LivestockSpeciesName AS LSN
      ON LSN.livestock_species_id = LS.id AND LSN.language_id = 1
WHERE
    LS.id = 1
```